# Facebook SDK for .NET: Uploading pics to a page from backend

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What I am looking to achieve. 
I have a WPF application where in, I will be getting access to some pics generated on run time and I wanna post these pics to an album on FB Page(Think server to server interaction ). This process is supposed to be completely self reliant without any input from users. So I did some research and figured you gotta create an app to be able to do it. On further research the process seems to be as follows:

1) Using app secret and app id , get the app access token 
2) Get the user access token 
3) using this user access token, call {userId}/accounts and from the resulting JSON parse the page id and get the Page Access token.

Now I have successfully retrieved the App Access token and now I am not able to figure out how to get UserAccessToken without which I cant proceed to step 3.

I am using C# SDK for facebook and here is some code

Step 1.

```
            var fbAccess = new FacebookClient();
            dynamic resultAccess = fbAccess.Get("oauth/access_token", new
            {
                client_id = "XXXXXXXXX",
                client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXX",
                grant_type = "client_credentials",
                redirect_uri = "",
                perms = "manage_pages, photo_upload, publish_stream"

            });
            String app_access_token = resultAccess["access_token"];
```

Step 2:

```
 FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient(app_access_token );
 dynamic resultAccess = fbClient.Get("/{UserID}/accounts", new
        {
            client_id = "XXXXXXX",
            client_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            perms = "manage_pages, photo_upload, publish_stream"

        });
```

The error I am getting is "A user access token is required to request this resource." I have already given the required permission to the app using Graph API Explorer.

Thanks in Advance